# Android highlight ImageButton onclick

Tags: android, onclick, highlight, imagebutton

Is there a way to highlight an `ImageButton` when it's pressed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define a drawable via XML and use the selector, like below, to use different (i.e. highlighted) images for different button states:

i.e. res/drawable/button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_catlocfilter" android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_catlocfilter_dark" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_catlocfilter" android:state_focused="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_catlocfilter_dark" android:state_focused="true" />

</selector>
```

Use this resource then for the ImageButton view.